# Retrieving Job Distribution List From Content Store

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

Using Cognos 10.2, I am trying to get a list of all my reports that are currently scheduled, and the distribution list that the scheduled reports will be sent to.

I can get a list of all standalone reports that are scheduled on their own, and their distribution lists, using the following code:

```
select ob2.cmid, 
c.name as className, 
n.name as objectName,
o.DELIVOPTIONS as DeliveryOptions

from CMOBJPROPS2 p

inner join (select cmid, cast(DELIVOPTIONS as nvarchar(2048)) as DELIVOPTIONS from CMOBJPROPS26) as o on p.cmid=o.cmid
inner join CMOBJECTS ob on ob.cmid=o.cmid
inner join CMOBJECTS ob2 on ob.pcmid=ob2.cmid
inner join CMOBJNAMES n on n.cmid=ob2.cmid
inner join CMCLASSES c on ob2.classid=c.classid
```

However I am also after all the reports that are scheduled within a job within cognos. The above shows me the jobs/events that are scheduled, but not the reports within the jobs and their distribution lists.

I have run tabular the CMOBJPROPS26 table and the DELIVOPTIONS field seems to contain the data I am after, which I can join using CMID back to the report names / jobs maybe, but when I am viewing the information that comes out, where I believe the email addresses should be it seems to have a long string instead. I think this might be because the emails from our work AD group which is connected to Cognos and not stored in Cognos itself. The system must have a look up or know how to translate this long string into the name from the work AD group, and I am wondering if anyone knew how I could do it?

My end goal is to have an output list that provides me report name - distribution list for all reports that contain a distribution list.

Many thanks

Comment: I ran your `data` through https://www.base64decode.org/.  There are no email addresses there.  It looks like it's just the body of the message.

Answer (score 1):

I think I tried this before and the conclusion I came to with limited time was, "Can't get there from here."  Remember this is a proprietary system.  IBM doesn't like us mucking about in their database.  IBM would say you need to use the SDK.

That being said...

It looks like you posted a very small piece of the DELIVOPTIONS value, and I think it's the wrong one.  I think there are two pieces from DELIVOPTIONS that you'll need.  They are labeled `to` and `toAddress`.  You'll need to parse the `<value>` tag from each as XML.

From `toAddress`, read the email addresses from the data.

From `to`, read the CAMID values from the data.  You can then join that result to CMOBJECTS33 to find the user name.  But that will only work for users registered in the Content Store.  That means probably only users who have logged into Cognos.  Also, I don't see email addresses for a user in the Content Store.  So for security groups and distribution groups (and probably users), you'll need to look that up using a query directly against your external namespace (like using openrowset to query your LDAP system from the database server, but you didn't say what RDBMS you use.).

Probably not the answer you wanted...

**Update to include job schedules (above is for report schedules)**

The email address info is with the jobStepDefinition object.  So if your jobDefinition object (the job) is CMID 123, you get your jobStepDefinition (the child of the jobDefinition object) like...

```
select o.CMID
, n.NAME as JobStepDefinition
, c.NAME as ClassName
, s.DELIVOPTIONS

from CMOBJECTS o
  inner join CMOBJNAMES n on n.CMID = o.CMID
  inner join CMCLASSES c on c.CLASSID = o.CLASSID
  inner join CMOBJPROPS26 s on s.CMID = o.CMID

where n.ISDEFAULT = 1
  and o.PCMID = 123
```

(That outputs the class name as well, so you can verify)
That's the basics.  You could get fancier with a CTE if you need to.

Now you need to parse some things as XML.  You'll evaluate them the same way I say to do so for schedules (above).

`toAddress`, `ccAddress`, `bccAddress` contain email addresses.
`to`, `cc`, `bcc` contain CAMID values.

Good luck.

Oh, and I haven't figured out yet how to list all of the reports run within a job.  Again, the SDK may be easier to use in this regard.

Comment: Thanks very much for this reply. I pulled that bit of DELIVOPTIONS as I thought that was where the addresses were kept but I was wrong, thanks for showing me where to look. I will look in DELIVOPTIONS for those particular areas. You have given me some extra things to look at and work through to see if I can get there. Understand IBM don't really like this, but for some reason our administrator has said the SDK is not available, so spending hours trying this is still time saved compared to doing it manually if I can get there. Thanks again!

Comment: Let's be fair to your admin.  The SDK has certain requirements:  an Analytics Administrator license ($$$), expertise in C# or Java, a willingness to learn the SDK (it's huge and not necessarily intuitive), and a willingness to wait for the program to run (SDK programs are very slow).